# Is there anything like Zope Page Templates for Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css

I have a Ruby on Rails app that I built myself, but which needs a redesign by a professional designer. I know most designers just give you Photoshop mockups and slices, but I would like to hire someone to implement the design as well, which means rewriting the css style sheets and the erb and haml templates.

The problem is that I want someone else to implement the redesign without exposing my code to the redesign implementer.  Also, I wish there was a way to allow a designer to implement a redesign on a Ruby on Rails site without having to know anything about Ruby on Rails.  Are either of these scenarios possible using any combination of software tools?

I guess I'm looking for something like Zope Page Templates, but for Ruby on Rails.

http://quintagroup.com/cms/zpt

Comment: If your business logic is in your views, then you're doing it wrong. Properly done, you can make your views similar to zpt.

Comment: I meant that I didn't want to expose my code to the design implementer, meaning that she should not have to check out my rails app from the repo and start it up to implement the design and test it.

Comment: I have designers marking up erb in Dreamweaver just fine. If you don't go hog wild on partials it's doable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been using a gem by dr nic that allows to quickly slap a html template on your rails site called [install_theme](https://github.com/drnic/install_theme).

It allows your designer to just code a pure html/css solution, which this gem then translates into a rails layout, and allows to fill in the partials and main content area automatically. You will still have to design/code your own views, but at least the main layout is achieved quickly.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I know a some of those.

A popular one is [liquid](http://www.liquidmarkup.org/). It's used on [Jekyll](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll) (which is powers [Github Pages](http://pages.github.com/)) and [Harmony](http://get.harmonyapp.com/).

There's also [mustache](http://mustache.github.com/). It's selling point is that it exists for lots of languages; even javascript. If you need a lot of flexibility (or enough rope to hang yourself) give it a look.

[Radiant](http://radiantcms.org/) has its own templating language (xml-based, if I remember correctly) but it looked just wrong to me.